# How to discover URL and command line parameters from Chrome processes

Tags: .net, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've written an app launcher in C# on Windows. Users can group apps together and launch them en bloc. It also does window positioning. It works fairly well.

Some users have asked for two new features:

- Close all apps that were launched en bloc
- Create a new group from all the apps that are currently running, and save their window positions

These sound like fun, but I'm hitting a big problem with dealing with chrome. Chrome deals with its own process management, which makes tying the act of launching chrome to the process/window that ultimately appears almost impossible.

Moreover, I can't easily discover what Chrome windows are currently running and the URLs they are browsing.

I can turn on the remote debugging port and discover some of this information, but that's not going to be a sustainable solution for most users.

What other techniques can I use to discover this information? It would be a big step forward for me to be able to say that chrome process X is connected to URL Y. Even better would be a way to close a chrome window programatically without killing X directly.

A chrome extension is a possibility, but I'm unsure how best to pass the data from that extension back to my app launcher.

Detours and DLL injection is also a possibility.

Any ideas, folks? Thank you.

Comment: Using WINAPI you can establish the relation of any chrome process by reading its parent pid, you can also find a window's process or all windows of a given process, as well as all child processes. A chrome extension would help with getting the list of tab urls, but it might be nontrivial/impossible to map them to pid.

Comment: I'm well versed in process enumeration, but what do you mean by "you can establish the relation of any chrome process by reading its parent pid" ?

Comment: I referred to "discover what Chrome windows are currently running" and "tying the act of launching chrome to the process/window". The main chrome.exe process is the parent so by analyzing parent pids you can find how the processes relate to each other i.e. who's daddy.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yes, that kind of thing is trivial but unfortunately doesn't lead me to answering any questions about the URL/window/process relationship.

Comment: Why process/window relationship is not enough and why URL is necessary?

Comment: Because imagine the scenario with my app launcher. The user adds three chromes, each with different urls. They launch those chromes and chrome does it thing of taking the processes that are launched and then proxying them through its own process management functions. The original three processes terminate and then everything is sandboxed within the chrome-managed environment.

If the user wants to then close all the apps that were launched as a group, there is no way to discover which chrome processes/windows relate to the three urls that were originally launched.

Comment: The original chrome.exe process doesn't terminate here, so it's possible to derive the entire relation graph, here's an example from system informer: https://puu.sh/K3tud/e24446ecb3.png, but even if it did the newly launched main browser process would have its parent pid of the original process.

Comment: I guess you refer to the case when chrome is already running, so the newly launched process only opens a new tab in the old tree, but why would it be impossible to handle?